# Piping SQL query result into another command in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I would like to create a module, which would have several functions related to user provisioning. The data would be pulled from a SQL database and piped as a result into an AD command (importing AD module is omitted in this example).
A sample is below:
Lets consider a table with users.

> Id, username, firstname, lastname, signed
>       1, joed, joe, doe, NULL
>       2, janes, jane, smith, 2/2/12
>       3, nickc, nick, cook, NULL
>       4, robh, rob, hunt, 3/3/13

```
Function Get-ContractSigned {
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()

BEGIN { 
# SQL Connection #
$server   = "SERVER"
$database = "Database" 
# formatting the table headers to correspond with Identity parameter of AdUser cmdlets
$q_contractSigned = "SELECT USERNAME as IDENTITY, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      WHERE signed IS NOT NULL"
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=true"
$sqlConn.Open()

# SQL command
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $q_contractSigned

PROCESS {
 $adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
 $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
 $adp.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
 $dataSet.Tables
}

END {
   $sqlConn.Close()
}
```

At this point the function displays the following output:

> Get-ContractSigned
>
> ```
> IDENTITY  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME
> janes       Jane        Smith
> robh        Rob         Hunt
> ```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
Get-ContractSigned | Enable-ADUser
```

but am not sure how to process this System.Data.DataTable

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with datatables and I don't have time to test right now to confirm but iirc this should work..

    `(Get-ContractSigned).identity | Enable-ADUser`

Comment: Hi Mike, the trouble is, that the dot notation does not work. When i pipe  `Get-ContractSigned` to `Get-Member` i see my properties listed, but when i try to access them in something like `Get-ContractSigned | Where-Object {$_.Identity -eq '*jane*'}` ISE will not recognize the property. I am really not sure what i am doing wrong here

Comment: If anyone wonders, for now i just exported the `System.Data.DataRow` type produced by the sql query into a temp csv and imported it back in for further processing. if i ever figure out how to do it directly, i will update this post